# How to routes to a specific controller with a variable value ahead of it in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Normally its like:
resources :users
To keep a value ahead we can do like

```
scope :url do
   resources :users
end
```

but, issue is that I have the just variable in front of the routes not a fixed value with few conditions for it.
Example in rails 2. and want to convert the routing accoding to rails5

> ```
> map.with_options :controller => 'users' do |user|
>   user.forgot_user ':url/users/forgot',   :action => 'forgot',  :url => /([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/
>   user.user ':url/users/retrieve',   :action => 'retrieve',  :url => /([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/
>   user.login       ':url/users/login',    :action => 'login',                                          :url => /([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/
>   user.logout      ':url/users/logout',   :action => 'logout',                                         :url => /([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/
>   user.new_user    ':url/users/new',      :action => 'new',     :conditions => { :method => :get },    :url => /([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/
>   user.users       ':url/users/:id',      :action => 'show',   :conditions => { :method => :get },    :url => /([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)/
> end
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "problem is that I have the just variable in front of the routes not a fixed value " Explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scope "/(:subdomain)", :defaults => {:subdomain => "default"} do
  ...
end
```

use subdomain as a variable.